# precision about the meaning of 筒抜け in the context

Tags: words

I did not understand how the following sentence has been translated

> 普通なら二度と口を利かないところだけれど、涙ぐましい努力だけは汲んでおいてあげるわ」
> 　どうやらこっちの友達が欲しいと言う狙い、思惑は全部**筒抜け**らしい。
>
> Normally, I wouldn’t want to hear you speak twice, but I will put in
> the painful effort to listen to you.” For some reason I tried to make
> friends with her, but my expectations were completely off.

"思惑は" means "expectations (in the sense of speculations) and I found that 筒抜け means "going in one ear and out the other" but that does not seem to apply here.
Could you help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

筒抜け is a no-adjective that means "to be completely leaked out", "to be completely seen through", "transparent" or "obvious". You've got the other parts of the sentences wrong.

- 汲む is "to take into consideration".
- 思惑 in this context means "(hidden) purpose", "(undisclosed) intent". It's in apposition with 狙い.
- 友達が欲しいという describes the content of 思惑/狙い.

> 「普通なら二度と口を利かないところだけれど、涙ぐましい努力だけは汲んでおいてあげるわ」
> "Normally I wouldn't talk to (someone like) you again, but for your sake I'll at least remember/consider this miserable effort (you've made) (, so you must thank me)."
>
> どうやらこっちの友達が欲しいと言う狙い、思惑は全部筒抜けらしい。
> Looks like my intent to make friends (with her or someone else) has been completely seen through by her.

Answer (score 1):

The secret is leaked to others.

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%AD%92%E6%8A%9C%E3%81%91/

> １ 物音や話し声が、そのまま他の人に聞こえること。**また、秘密の内容などがそっくり他に漏れてしまうこと。**「筒抜けに耳にはいる」**「計画が相手方に筒抜けになる」**
>
> ２ 人の話などが頭の中にとどまらないで通りぬけてしまうこと。「せっかくの忠告も右から左へ筒抜けだ」

Comment: thanks a lot but I was asking for the meaning in this case; in fact I cannot match the English translation with either of the definitions

Comment: @Makoto Why are you so certain that the English translation is correct?

Comment: @Ringil I am currently learning by reading novels and comparing Japanese text and its official translation, which can, of course, slightly differ from the original text

Comment: @Makoto That seems like a reasonable overall strategy. However, are you sure that's an official translation? Those tend to have a few errors, but rarely as big as the translation you posted, which is why I have some doubts as to the pedagogical value of the translation you are using.

Comment: @Ringil yes it is an official translation from a light novel ebook on Amazon and you are right, sometimes it differs but it is a good exercise, because it forces me to ask the right questions

Comment: @Makoto Oh I didn't know that was an official translation made by a professional. Perhaps you have to read this translator's translations with a grain of salt...

Comment: @naruto yes you are right